# Both my if and else statements are executing in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to create a basic script whereby a user provides one or more paths and if that path is valid, the script proceeds.

However in my if statement, an invalid path returns both a success and failure message which will confuse the user and frankly, is confusing me.

Here is my code:

```
from os import path

#set a variable as False that will keep you locked in the loop until
#a valid input is provided and it is turned to True.
valid_input = False
#Start the while loop that requests user provides paths
while not valid_input:
    search_locations_str = input("Please provide the name of the loaction\nyou would like to search by inputting the\nfull path.\n \nTo search multiple locations, simply input\nmultiple paths separated by a comma and a space.")
    print("\n")
    search_locations = search_locations_str.split(", ")
    print("area(/s) to search ", search_locations)
#Add a for stament that can end the loop if, after checking the users input, 
#the paths are valid and actually exist. 
    for search_location in search_locations:
        if path.exists(search_location)==False:
            print(search_location + " not recognised, please amend or remove" )

    else:
        valid_input = True
        print(search_location + " identified, search for useful files can proceed")
```

If you put in a valid path, it works perfectly.

If you put in an invalid path, it tells you the path is both valid and invalid:

```
area(/s) to search  ['non/existent/path']
non/existent/path not recognised, please amend or remove
non/existent/path identified, search for useful files can proceed
```

Comment: If the indentation in your sample above is accurate, you have `else` lined up with `for`, not with `if`.  This means the `else` clause is executed after the loop ends (weird terminology, but that's the way it is).  You should line up the `else` with the `if`.

Comment: @DaveCosta Thanks I thought I had checked the indentation but you were correct and moving the `else` worked. If you post it as an answer I can mark it as correct. I think your comment is about all the explanation needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentation is not correct in your code. The `else` should be on the same level as the `if`.

**Correct indentation:**

```
for search_location in search_locations:
    if path.exists(search_location)==False:
        print(search_location + " not recognised, please amend or remove" )
    else:
        valid_input = True
        print(search_location + " identified, search for useful files can proceed")
```

On the other hand `for/else` is also a valid case. You can read more details about it on this page: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html